# Exchange, AD and Outlook user photos

Tags: exchange, active-directory, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm having a strange problem and wouldn't mind some insight on some areas to check. I have two users each with their own photo in AD.

- User 1
- User 2

User 1 is showing as themselves, while user 2 is showing as user 1. I've tried removing both entries in the "*thumbnail photo*" AD attribute as I understand the exchange GAL basically points to that field but nothing changes.

Here's the strange part, the photo sync works flawlessly on my own PC and on Sharepoint yet it shows up incorrectly on the other 20+ users I've tested on (it also shows incorrectly on OWA). It's a mix of on-line and cached exchange setups.

If there's any more info I can provide or clear up please let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, if the photo was uploaded from OWA, then it cannot be changed by AD.

You need to remove it from OWA, then upload the new photo from AD. Or change the photo from OWA directly.